# Finding the corresponding constrained subspace under a over determined mapping Ax=b, where b is constrained

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Suppose that $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix with m>n, $Ax=b$, and $b$ is constrained in every component, $b_\min^i<b_i<b_\max^i$ for $i=1,\dots,m$. There should be a similar set of constraints for $x$: $x_\min^i<x_i<x_\max^i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ such that $Ax$ satisfy the constraint for $b$, and such that for every $b$ in the range of A, that satisfies the constraint on $b$, there should be an $x$ that satisfies $x_\min^i<x_i<x_\max^i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ such that $Ax=b$.

Does anyone know if there is an efficient way of finding these constraints?

Sorry for the very long title, but I couldn't think of something more concise.

Answer (score 1):

> There should be a similar set of constraints for $x$

No, there is no  such set of constraints in general. Not every $n$-dimensional axes-aligned rectangular box is the image of some $m$-dimensional axes-aligned  rectangular box. For example, let 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1  & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and consider the square $Q=\{(b_1,b_2) : 0< b_1,b_2< 1\}$. The inverse image of this square under $A$ is $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) : 0<x_1+x_2<1, 0<x_2< 1\}$ which is a parallelogram.

If $E$ is a rectangle contained in this parallelogram, then $A(E\times  \mathbb R)$ is a proper subset of $Q$. The reason is that the third coordinate does not really contribute, and when restricted to the first two coordinates, $A$ is one-to-one.